# Could InSight lift off and move somewhere else?

Tags: mars, nasa, lander, insight

InSight used its built-in thrusters for the final stretch of the Entry, Descent and Landing, and the thrusters seem to still be attached.  Would it have been at all possible for InSight to lift off again, just a bit, and move over slightly if NASA found it's first landing spot a serious challenge to its scientific goals for some reason?

Comment: strictly humor: You've solved the problem of what the impactor will be in this case: [How could InSight's seismometers be intentionally and meaningfully “pinged”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32104/12102)

Comment: Thrusters would allow it. There's probably not enough fuel margin to go very far. The landing gear might have single-use crush cores that would make a second landing very rough on the hardware.

Comment: Even if the surface is too hard for HP3, keep in mind that the spacecraft also has sensors for seismometry, air temperature, pressure, wind, and magnetic field; a precision radio transponder; and two cameras. **All of these other instruments will work fine without moving the spacecraft.** The failure of one instrument will not mean end-of-mission.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possible, but **very likely to cause damage** to the spacecraft.  Let's look at the lander's systems:

- Engines: reusable.  InSight uses 20 thrusters of three different models, all built by Aerojet.  They all use the same hydrazine monopropellant, and can be restarted.  The engines vary from 1,500 to 275,000 duty cycles -- more than enough.
- Propellant: maybe enough.  The mission is designed with reserve fuel.  However, it is difficult to predict fuel usage:

> Over the course of the mission, as propellant is expended, tank and feed pressures will decline and cause engine thrust and specific impulse to decrease – requiring detailed analysis of the thruster response to decreasing inlet pressure to ensure accurate maneuvering over the course of the mission.

- Landing legs: **no.**  The shock absorbers on the legs are one-use only.

> Shock absorption is accomplished with an aluminum honeycomb crush core that functions in the form of a compressible cartridge between an inner and outer cylinder to serve as a one-use shock absorber.

[image: InSight legs]
<sub>(source: [spaceflight101.com](https://spaceflight101.com/insight/wp-content/uploads/sites/216/2018/03/insight-14.jpg))</sub>

- Batteries: sure, after they are given a full recharge.
- Solar panel: risky.  The panels were folded in a circular-pleated pattern prior to launch.  They are already extended, and not designed to be retracted and re-folded.  Damage would be likely if the craft flew with them extended.
- IMU and landing radar: no problem.  It uses accelerometers, ring-laser gyros, and a conventional radar to guide landing.  All can be easily restarted.
- Robotic arm: probably okay.  Even if it didn't return entirely to its stowed position, it should be fine.
- Cameras: risky.  There are dust covers which must be removed to survey the site, before you'd make a decision to re-launch.  You can't put those dust covers back on.  The camera under the deck (ICC) particularly got a lot of dust during landing.

Source: http://spaceflight101.com/insight/insight-spacecraft/

Comment: Dang it, someone else posted an answer while I was composing this one.

Comment: Ha I got you! But you explained it in more detailed way for sure. Kudos to you.

Comment: Presumably for a small lateral hop of a few meters, the shock absorbers would not be as necessary as they would be for the initial reentry and landing. Also there's no guarantee they were completely crushed the first time. Being designed as single-use doesn't automatically meant there's no crush left. So based on what's here so far, I think the legs are a probable "go" and not at all a firm no.

Comment: @uhoh: It's true that we'll know a lot more once they get the robotic arm going next week and start taking pictures.  Suffice to say, there are plenty of things that can go wrong.

Comment: Also, since the solar panels can't be folded in, they'd be coated in dust from any hypothetical takeoff and landing

Comment: Timing the messages between '17 meters' and 'Touchdown confirmed', the landing speed was slightly above 1m/s. I seriously doubt the shock absorbers were 'used up' to any degree, especially if they are to make a difference if the landing speed differs considerably from planned,

Comment: I really, really wonder why they didn't just include a small compartment with a duster brush grippable by the robotic arm.

Comment: @SF. Geez that's a face-palmable idea! If you can make it sufficiently different from this question go ahead and ask!  **update:** oh, it has been asked! [Brushing clean a Mars lander's solar panels](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32445/12102)

Comment: I didn't really understand the honeycomb design you mentioned, what about it was honeycombed and one-time-use for the 200mm crush stroke or whatever was mentioned in the diagram?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Inside the blue can on the lander leg is some metal shaped like a honeybee's honeycomb.  When the ends of the can are pressed together with enough force, the honeycomb crushes by a distance of up to 200 mm.  This allows the lander leg to absorb energy, yet still remain functional.  The process cannot be undone.  It's designed for the worst case.  As some of the discussion here noted, we won't know how much actually happened until the cameras take pictures of the legs.

Comment: @DrSheldon interesting, so when the camera pans down to the legs are we expecting... something akin to a jumped-on soda can? Or something much less extreme?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Crushing a soda can is a good analogy.  The extent of the crushing will depend on how much energy was absorbed by the impact.  As SF pointed out, the landing appears to have been quite gentle, and it's possible that little or no deformation happened on any number of legs.

Comment: @DrSheldon awesome, thanks for the clarification. I may ask a follow up for the specifications on the theoretical maximum force the legs could've taken on impact.

Comment: @SF. I think you are reading far too much into "touchdown confirmed" from the PAO, and we also do not know the design strength of the crush core. Between the one-use only landing legs, the irrevocable removal of the dust covers, and the irrevocable deployment of the solar panels, the answer to the question is a resounding **NO** rather than a mere possible.

Comment: @DavidHammen if staying put meant EOM, I'm still not able to understand why at least a small propulsive lift would absolutely never be considered under any circumstances. Unless there's something like an intentionally burned-out fuse blocking re-ignition, I don't see where the absolute no comes from exactly.

Comment: Apparently Phonexi used less than 70% of it's hydrazine in its landing. The remain hydrazine was expected to freeze during the first night. The backshell/heatshield kept everything warm (by preventing radiative cooling of the electronics) during the cruise stage, so there's no need for heaters.

Answer (score 4):

This [article](http://spaceflight101.com/insight/insight-spacecraft/) provides a very detail overview to InSight spacecraft. It goes through variety of perspectives from Cruise Stage to Aeroshell & Parachute, Lander Structure, Electric Power System, Propulsion & Atttitude Actuation, Attitude Determination, Landing Radar and finally Data Handling & Telecommunications. First, you'd need to know why InSight lands on where it was landed.

### Why NASA chose Elysium Planitia as InSight's home on Mars?

From an initial menu of 22 potential landing sites, the InSight team decided that only three were strong candidates, and of those, Elysium Planitia stood out as being flattest, without too many rocks or gusts of wind to potentially upset the lander. <sup>[source](https://www.space.com/42509-insight-mars-landing-site-elysium-planitia.html)</sup>
[image]
<sup>An artist's depiction of Elysium Planitia, where NASA's InSight lander will touch down on Nov. 26.</sup> <sup>Credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech</sup>

> The team considered two key criteria as they decided where to place the lander. The first is safety. Landing on Mars is always a challenge because of the planet's thin atmosphere, so the InSight team wanted a patch of fairly flat land to reduce the risk of the three-legged robot toppling over at touchdown.
>
> The second factor, of course, is science. It's particularly important that the landing site meet the team's research needs since InSight is a lander and can't move itself around the Martian surface: Where it lands is where it will learn.
>
> That meant the location needed to be able to accommodate InSight's instruments, especially the probe that will hammer itself 16 feet (5 meters) below the surface in order to measure the planet's below-ground temperature.
>
> Other constraints included someplace warm and sunny enough to keep InSight's electronics happy, and to let its two large, circular solar power arrays create enough energy to keep the robot going.

That said, Elysium Planitia practically is the flattest spot that NASA could found on Mars as the best landing site to fulfill InSight's scientific requirements in the meantime avoids any future concern as much as possible.

### How big and heavy is the InSight?

The InSight Lander is 5 ft. 1 inch (1.56m) wide and 19 feet 8 inches (6m) long and weights 794 pounds (360 kg) which is roughly the weight of about 5 adult people.

### What instruments does the InSight Lander have?

[SEIS](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/spacecraft/instruments/seis/): A seismometer that can provide information on internal vibrations or Marsquakes occurring within the Red Planet. Depending on the material the vibrations propagate through will change the way the seismic waves travel which when detected can tell scientists what the materials are.

[HP3](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/spacecraft/instruments/hp3/): A heat probe that will burrow almost 16 feet (5 m) into Mars’ surface – the deepest to date. The probe will help scientists measure Mars’ temperature and work out whether Mars was formed from the same materials as Earth or not.

[RISE](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/spacecraft/instruments/rise/): A radio wave instrument that can help scientists work out the size of Mars’ core as well as its composition by sending out a signal and seeing how it changes in frequency via the Doppler shift.

[Instrument Deployment and Instrument Context Camera](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/spacecraft/about-the-lander/): The former being a camera that offers a 360-degree panoramic view of the Martian land in color. The latter being a camera that will take ‘fisheye’ field of view of the Lander’s workspace.

While SEIS & HP3 would have to deploy on the ground in the following weeks on Mars, that is why InSight was designed as a stationary machine and its main goal is to study Mars interior core.

---

Now back to topic with the relevant [article](http://spaceflight101.com/insight/insight-spacecraft/) I have provided above.

> Would it have been at all possible for InSight to lift off again, just a bit, and move over slightly if NASA found it's first landing spot a serious challenge to its scientific goals for some reason?

I'd say this is unlikely to happen as the landing site was carefully chosen with the reference above. It's relatively impossible that NASA would faces a 'serious challenge' on the spot.

In **Lander Structure** section:

> Because no active hazard-avoidance is used by InSight, the legs must be capable of supporting worst-case landing scenarios like 16° slope and up to 40cm rocks in combination.

The biggest challenge for InSight to touchdown would be the potential risk of flip over; if its lander legs are so lucky to land on slope, rocks or in combination. Since InSight already successfully touchdown on Mars without issue, there is no point to lift off and move over a bit in general.

In **Propulsion & Attitude Actuation** section:

> The Propulsion Subsystem of the InSight Lander is identical to that flown on Phoenix – featuring a total of 20 thrusters broken down in three different groups: 1) **Reaction Control System** thrusters with a nominal thrust of 4.5 Newtons, 2) **Trajectory Correction Thrusters** operating at 22 Newtons and 3) **Pulsed Landing Thrusters** generating 293 Newtons of thrust for attitude control and velocity reduction during the Mars Landing Maneuver. All thrusters are fed from two central tanks containing ~65 Kilograms of usable propellant.

In a nutshell, I think there was no thruster particularly designed for InSight to lift off. Even if it could, as most of the hardwares were 'exposed' after the first successful landing, a second landing <sup>(even just a small ones)</sup> would probably causes sabotage. If you're expecting a hypothetical answer, maybe someone else could answers you. It would be interesting, though.

Comment: "...no thruster was designed for InSight to lift off." How do you know? Why would that require a special design? What would the difference be? "...a second landing (even just a small ones) would probably causes sabotage." Why? So far you seem to be sidestepping the question; *Could InSight lift off and move somewhere else?* Yes? No?

Comment: I edited my response in a rather opinion way, I shouldn't be so sure about the thruster without research. Regarding to sidestepping the questions, I see the question in a 'rather hypothetical' question. An exact response of **_Yes_** or **_No_** wouldn't be appropriate in my opinion. Any improvements for my response are welcomed.

Comment: Question asks if it could, you want to explain why it wouldn't be necessary. That's fine to include, but is it possible to address the question as asked directly as well? *Could InSight lift off and move somewhere else?* Yes? No?

Comment: According to your answer, the thrusters are powerful enough to allow takeoff. I asked a related question here: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32436/how-much-fuel-is-left-in-insight

Comment: Considering there's likely at least a little fuel left, there's certainly enough thrust, they are variable thrust, there is ground-sensing radar and an excellent ADCS system, and they started once already, it looks like the answer could be yes, unless there's a hardware lock that makes restart impossible for safety reasons which is certainly a good idea and plausible.

Comment: @Antzi you may want to ask about a hardware lock (see above) in your question there as well. Remaining fuel wouldn't be useful if there's some un-reopenable valve in the way.

Comment: There are switches in the legs to stop the engines, but they are probably software, additional safeing mechanisms to seal the pipes are a possibility.  But instead of asking if there's enough fuel to takeoff, the question should be is there enough fuel to take-off, rotate to provide significant lateral velocity to reach a different location, rotate again to cancel that velocity in a gravity turn and land?

Comment: `-1` There's a large amount of generic background information here, but I still can't tell what your answer is. *Could InSight lift off and move somewhere else?* Yes? No?