# How was the landing site decided to land InSight?

Tags: landing, insight, image-processing, site-selection

From this [article](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/timeline/prelaunch/landing-site-selection/)

> The High-Resolution Imaging Science Experiment (HiRISE) camera on NASA's Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter plays an important role in evaluating candidate landing sites on Mars. HiRISE took about 150 images of candidate InSight landing sites, covering nearly all of the ground of the final site.

I came to know that the site selection 150 images were taken to land InSight Mars lander. But to process those images, what kind of processing was done to identify the flat ground, rocks, craters, etc.?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter#HiRISE_(camera)): "To facilitate the mapping of potential landing sites, HiRISE can produce stereo pairs of images from which topography can be calculated to an accuracy of 0.25 m (9.8 in)."
Stereo pairs allow to identify the flat ground, rocks, craters. This technique was used in WW II with aerial photographs. Two different images made of the same area but from different viewpoints allow 3D vision using both eyes.

Comment: Acording to this week's [Interplanetary podcast](https://www.interplanetary.org.uk/single-post/2018/11/30/Insight-and-Generation-Ships) mission of the week, the requirements were for an equatorial (to keep the solar panels lit all year round), low-elevation (to give aero-breaking enough air & time to work), flat area (for ease of landing) with a soft surface (for the HP$^3$ probe).

Comment: @Uwe: That would make a good answer, why not do it?

Comment: This answer to another question hits on this a lot: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32435/25224