# Is planetary impact testing planned for the InSight Mars lander's seismometers?

Tags: mars, planetary-science, insight, planning, seismology

The question [How could InSight's seismometers be intentionally and meaningfully “pinged”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32104/12102) is a hypothetical and has several good speculative answers.

But here I'd like to ask specifically about any *planned experiments.*

Seeing as insight is originally made to detect earthquakes, and because lunar seismic detectors have been used to detect impact events, is it planned to slam a rocket body, orbiter, or any other artificial impactor into the surface some distance away from INSIGHT and detect the propagation of the waves caused by the impact?

As a side question, are there any current or future candidate objects are big enough to be potentially of use for this?

Comment: @uhoh thanks, I just got to a computer and this is much better.

Comment: 28 October 2022: [*Largest recent impact craters on Mars: Orbital imaging and surface seismic co-investigation*](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abq7704). The Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter is used to locate the [location of the impact](https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2022-10-28/mars-impact-craters-send-seismic-waves-around-red-planet/101579182).