# Will InSight be able to pick up vibrations from the landing of Perseverance or Tianwen?

Tags: mars, insight, perseverance, al-amal-emm, tianwen-1

In roughly six months, two spacecrafts will be landing on Mars. Will the seismometers on InSight be able to detect vibrations from any of those landings?

Comment: I thought about this. I could imagine that the impact of the decent stage is strong enough for InSight to detect it.

Comment: related, but your question is different. [How could InSight's seismometers be intentionally and meaningfully “pinged”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32104) with *four answers* and [InSight and active pinging of Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32091) with *two answers*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I really hope it won't be able to detect Hope, that's orbiting Mars, not landing on it.

InSight was actually [made to detect](https://www.seis-insight.eu/en/public-2/martian-science/meteoritical-impacts) these impacts, as it can help one to understand more about Mars. Fundamentally a heat shield impacting is just a particularly dense meteor.

I think it is likely it will detect Perseverance. The two are fairly close. Specifically it should detect the heat shield crashing, which is known to leave a small crater. This is the very similar Curiosity heat shield, that makes a dent when it lands!

[image]

We don't know as much about the Chinese lander, but it is smaller, and is expected to land in Utopia Planitia. That is also relatively close to InSight. I would expect it also to register.